# Return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target

Tags: java, algorithm

I have the below question I am trying to solve:

> Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

I have the below array as input - [2, 7, 11, 15] with target = 9.

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].

This is my code -

```
import java.util.Random;

public class TwoSum {

    static int[] numbers = new int[] {2, 7, 11, 15};
    int[] indices = new int[numbers.length];

    public static int[] returnIndices(int target, int[] inputArr) {
        int[] indices = new int[2];
        int randomOne = new Random().nextInt(inputArr.length);
        int randomTwo = new Random().nextInt(inputArr.length);
        while(true) {
            if(target == inputArr[randomOne] + inputArr[randomTwo]) {
                indices[0] = randomOne;
                indices[1] = randomTwo;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("done");
        return indices;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] output = returnIndices(9, numbers);
    }

}
```

Is this the right way to approach my problem?

Comment: Do you need to find _all_ such matching index pairs, or can you stop upon finding the first one?

Comment: I can stop on finding the first one. My program doesn't even compile lol

Comment: `doesn't even compile` ... given your rep level, don't you think you should at least post working Java code?

Comment: why are you choosing random indexes rather than looping?

Comment: What is wrong with your program?

Comment: Is sorting allowed?

Comment: It looks like this question was abandoned, with the provided code not compiling. It can still be repaired by producing a [mcve], but in the meantime I will cast a close vote.

Comment: while loop checks infinitely in case of there are no two elements who add up to the target , so this approach wont work

Answer (score 8):

You can use a hashmap to store the first array in the following manner:

```
   key  value(index in array)
    2 - 0
    7 - 1
    11 - 2
    15 - 3
```

Next get the target element which is 9, and start traversing your given array from index 0.

Element at index 0 is 2 --> calculate (9-2) = 7 --> check if 7 is a key in the hashmap

Additional Note: You need to take care of the following case:

arr = [3, 2, 1, 1] target = 6 (no answer exists in this case, but by the above method, when you calculate 6-3 = 3 you get index 0 as the answer.)

But this can easily be taken care of by checking whether (target-arr[i] == arr[i]) returns true or not. If it returns true and if the hashmap has two indices stored at the key arr[i], then return it as an answer, else proceed to the next element.

Comment: also maybe useful to work backwards through the list l

Comment: If you hunt for the keys in a single pass, then `6-3=3` issue will never arise.

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to solve this question:

1. Hashmap way - @mettleap [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53001917/return-indices-of-the-two-numbers-such-that-they-add-up-to-a-specific-target/53001958#53001958) has covered that one.
2. Sort-Array way - I am going to explain its pseudo code to you.

Let us take an example to see it in action first. We are given `arr = [5, 2, 1, 9, 7]` elements in an array, and we are to find the indices of two elements if we can make `8`.

If you look closely, then you will know if we sum 3rd + last element in an array, we will get `8`, which means `2` and `4` would be our answer. ***So How would be land there?*** Let us go step by step

1. Maintain a separate array of the same size, it will hold the indices of `arr` in its initial setup.

   ```
   [5, 2, 1, 9, 7] = arr
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] = index_arr
   ```
2. Now sort `arr` in increasing order, and also sort the `index_arr` such that index of elements in `arr` in their initial setup is still in place.

   ```
   [1, 2, 5, 7, 9] = arr
   [2, 1, 0, 4, 3] = index_arr
   ```
3. Use the below pseudo code:

   ```
   low  = 0
   high = length of arr - 1

   while (low < high) {
       sum = arr[low] + arr[high]

       if (sum  == number) {}
           print "index_arr[low]" and "index_arr[high]" 
           break the loop and exit
       } else if ( sum < number ) {
           low = low + 1
       } else {
           high = high - 1
       }
   }
   ```

   Let us see psuedo code in action:

   ```
   [1, 2, 5, 7, 9] = arr
   [2, 1, 0, 4, 3] = index_arr

   Iteration # 01
   low = 0 and high = 4
   sum = arr[0] + arr[4] = 1 + 9 = 10
   10 > 8 , means 'else' will be executed high = high - 1 = 4 - 1 = 3

   Iteration # 02
   low = 0 and high = 3
   sum = arr[0] + arr[3] = 1 + 7 = 8
   8 == 8 , means first 'if' condiion will execute, and will indices and exit the loop
   ```

**Time Complexity**  - O(n)
**Space Complexity** - O(n)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it in c#, It may help..

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            int[] nums = { 2, 7, 11, 15 };
            int target = 9;
            int[] result= TwoSumNumbers(nums, target);
        }

        public static int[] TwoSumNumbers(int[] nums, int target)
        {
            Dictionary<int, int> numsDict = new Dictionary<int, int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
            {
                int num = nums[i];

                if (numsDict.TryGetValue(target - num, out int index))
                {
                    return new[] { index, i };
                }

                numsDict[num] = i;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    int [] answer = new int[2];
    Map<Integer,Integer> values = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    for ( int i=0; i < nums.length; i++){
        values.put(nums[i],i);
    }
    for ( int i=0; i < nums.length; i++){
        int val = target - nums[i];
        Integer secondIndex = values.get(val);
        if ( secondIndex != null && secondIndex != i){
            answer[0] = i;
            answer[1] = secondIndex;
            return answer;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

C# Version

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Linq;

        namespace MyBasics
        {
            class ArrayIndexForTarget
            {
                public static void Main()
                {
                    ArrayIndexForTarget find = new ArrayIndexForTarget();
                    int[] arr = new int[] { 9, 2, 3, 9, 10 };
                    int target = 11;
                    var result = find.IndexFinder(arr, target);
    
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
             public  int[]  IndexFinder(int[]myArray,int target)
                {
                    int[] arr = new int[2];
                    Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();

                    for (int p=0; p < myArray.Length; p++) 
                    {
                        int numberToFind = target - myArray[p];
                        if (dict.ContainsValue(numberToFind))
                        {
                            arr[0] = dict.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == numberToFind).Key;
                            arr[1] = p;
                            return arr;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dict.Add(p,myArray[p]);
                        }
                    }
                    return arr;

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
    function twoSum($nums, $target) {        
        $lenght = count($nums);
        $indices = array();
        for($i = 0; $i<$lenght-1; $i++){
            for($j=$i+1; $j<$lenght; $j++){
                if(($nums[$i]+$nums[$j]) == $target){
                    $indices[] = $i;
                    $indices[] = $j;
                    
                    return $indices;
                }
            }
                
        }
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static int[] findNumbersToAdd(int target, int[] array) {
    int[] answer = {-1, -1};
    int length = array.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int var1 = array[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
            int var2 = array[j];
            if (var1 + var2 == target) {
                answer[0] = i;
                answer[1] = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

---

Comment: Can you edit explain why your code would work? Code only answer is considered not an answer and subject to removable.

Answer (score 0):

Given you aren't focused on performance I would think a brute force approach would be fine. Here is a solution using streams and records.

```
record IndexPair(int index1, int index2) { };
IntStream.range(0, arr.length).boxed()
    .flatMap(i1 -> IntStream.range(i1, arr.length)
        .filter(i2 -> arr[i1] + arr[i2] == target)
        .mapToObj(i2 -> new IndexPair(i1, i2))
    .forEach(ip -> ...);
```

If you only want one solution then you could use `findAny` instead of `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this question and implement it using HashMap in Java and it works completely fine.

```
public class Solution {
public int[] twoSum(final int[] A, int B) {
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> hm=new HashMap<>();

    int index1=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int index2=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int diff=0;

    for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
        diff=B-A[i];
        if(hm.containsKey(diff)){
            index2=i;
            index1=hm.get(diff);
            return new int[] {index1+1,index2+1};
        }else{
            if(!hm.containsKey(A[i])){
                hm.put(A[i],i);
            }
        }
    }
// If Arrays doesnt have such pairs   
if(index2 == (Integer.MAX_VALUE) || index1 == (Integer.MAX_VALUE)){
    return new int[] {};
}
return new int[] {index1+1,index2+1};

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple solution with 2 running loops,
assuming the following

1. you only need 2 numbers to get to the target.
2. the solution exists (therefor no need to validate).

   ```
    public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        for (int i=0; i< nums.Length; i++){
            for (int j=i+1; j< nums.Length; j++){
                if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                    return new int[]{i,j};
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
public  int[] sumofTwo(int[] numbers, int target)
{
 
    int[] answer = new int[2];
    Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numbers.length ; i++)
    {
        if(map.containsKey(target - numbers[i]))
        {
            answer[0] = map.get(target - numbers[i]);
            answer[1] = i;
            return answer;
        }
        else
        {
            map.put(numbers[i],i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
int [] arr = {4,7,1,-3,2};

    for(int i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<=arr.length-2; j++)
        {
            if((arr[i]+arr[j+1])==6)
            { 
                System.out.println("indices = "+"["+i +","+(j+1)+"]");
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```